# How to use derived type in specialisation of return-type function template? ("couldn't infer template argument")

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization

I have a template class and a function with a template return type:

```
template<typename T>
class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper(const T& _data) : data(_data) { }

    const T& get_data() {return data;};
private:
    T data;
};

template <typename T>
Wrapper<T> build_wrapped(){
    T t{};
    return Wrapper<T>(t);
}
```

Suppose that I want to extend the returned `Wrapper` for one specific type `T` and specialise the `build_wrapped()` function for the type. So, let's create a template to hold the return type and use it in `build_wrapped()`:

```
template<typename T>
struct ReturnType {
    using type = Wrapper<T>;
};

template <typename T>
typename ReturnType<T>::type build_wrapped(){
    T t{};
    return typename ReturnType<T>::type(t);
}
```

And use it to provide the specialization:

```
struct Foo{};

class ExtendedWrapper : public Wrapper<Foo> {
public:
    ExtendedWrapper(const Foo& _data) : Wrapper(_data) {}
    int get_answer() {return 42;};
};

template<>
struct ReturnType<Foo> {
    using type = ExtendedWrapper;
};

template<>
typename ReturnType<Foo>::type build_wrapped(){
    Foo t{};
    return typename ReturnType<Foo>::type(t);
}
```

However, the final declaration is rejected by both gcc and clang. For example, [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/8rITN4) returns:

> error: no function template matches function template specialization
>   'build_wrapped'
>
> note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'

I can get around using `ReturnType` by creating an explicit specialisation of `Wrapper` for `Foo`. However, this requires duplicating all the code in `Wrapper` (in my real life case it's a substantial class), when I just want to add some new functionality (as in `ExtendedWrapper`). So, can this be done? What's wrong with the approach above?

Comment: One alternative is to have tag and then use overload:: `template <typename T> struct tag{}; template <typename T>
Wrapper<T> build_wrapped(tag<T>) { return Wrapper<T>{{}};} ExtendedWrapper build_wrapped(tag<Foo>) { return ExtendedWrapper{{}};}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler already told you what the problem is:

> note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'

You need to specify the template parameter explicitly.

```
template <>
typename ReturnType<Foo>::type build_wrapped<Foo>()
{ //                                        ^~~~~
    Foo t{};
    return typename ReturnType<Foo>::type(t);
}
```

Comment: Good catch! Thanks!

Comment: @user44168 If the answer solved your problem you should mark it as accepted to indicate that (and give the person answering a bit of rep), not just comment "good catch".

Comment: @JesperJuhl yeah, well, SO forces you to wait until 10 minutes had passed since posting before you can accept.